# How can I copy all events from one calendar to another?

Tags: google-calendar, export, import, copy-paste

Normally if you want to copy all Google Calendar events from one calendar to another, you'd [export from one and import into the other](https://www.lifewire.com/copy-or-move-all-events-google-calendar-1172181). However, if the calendar isn't your own, the export feature isn't available. Is there another way to accomplish this short of copying each event individually?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the other calendar is shared with you and available in the "Other Calendars" section in Google Calendar, you can save the ICS version of the calendar and import that into your own.

To do this:

1. Go to Google Calendar Click the ellipsis to the right of the "other
   calendar" that has all the events.
2. Select `Settings`.
3. In the Integrate Calendar section, find and copy the `Public address in iCal format` url, similar to the example screenshot below.
   [image: example iCAL field in Google Calendar]
4. Then, paste the url into a separate browser tab/window.
5. Depending on your browser settings, you may be prompted to save the file once the page loads; otherwise, if it renders in the browser, choose `File > Save As`, and save the .ics file to your computer.
6. Finally, go to `Settings > General > Import`. Select and import the .ics file into your personal Google Calendar.

Comment: I can't find Public address in iCal format. Did they remove that?

Comment: As of Feb 25th, 2021. There is no more iCal format url, it's a URL that opens a Google Calendar without option to save as .ics file

Comment: In chrome, `File->Save As` only offers to save as HTML

Answer (score 2):

An embedded (or embeddable) calendar will have some possibly very long URL starting with

`http://www.google.com/calendar/embed?`

Within the possibly very long URL, you will find one or more parts of the form

`src=NUMBERSANDLETTERS%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%238D6F47&`

or

`src=USERNAME@%40gmail.com&color=%23A32929&`

Select either the `NUMBERSANDLETTERS%40group.calendar.google.com` or the `USERNAME@%40gmail.com` part and copy it.

Now take the following URL:

`https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/HERE/public/basic.ics`

and replace `HERE` with what you copied from above.

You will obtain an `ics` file that you should be able to use either in an app/external program, or in Google Calendar itself, by selecting the option "Add calendar" -> "From URL".

Clearly all of this will only work if the calendar is public - but if you have it embedded somewhere, it is public.

Answer (score 0):

When you importing calendar from URL you have to click checkbox to make new calendar publicly available, and then you have link to ical format

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** as of Jan 30th, 2023, since Google Calendar settings have changed --

As another answer has already stated in this thread:

> If the other calendar is shared with you and available in the "Other
> Calendars" section in Google Calendar, you can save the ICS version of
> the calendar and import that into your own.

Here is how to do it:

**Part 1: Retrieve Calendar ICS file**

1. Go to Google Calendar
2. From `Other Calendars` section: Click the ellipsis that appears on hover of the "other calendar" that has all of the events you wish to import
3. Select `Settings`
4. From `Calendar settings`: copy the `URL` link (this should be a link to the calendar's .ics file)
5. Paste the URL copied above into a new browser tab or window
6. Download the .ics file (you may be prompted to Save the file automatically, or if not prompted, go to `File > Save As` to download)

**Part 2: Import ICS file into an existing Calendar**

7. Lastly, go to `Settings > Import & Export`, select the other calendar's .ics file from your computer (*Step 6 above*) to import into an existing calendar of your choosing